# Can the name of the templated variable and the variable be the same?

Tags: jinja2, ansible-template

I am using the template module to replace a variable value, but it will not work when the key and the value names are the same:

```
variable_name: {{ variable_name }}
```

I can work around this by renaming the value to something other than the name:

```
variable_name: {{ variable_name_new }}
```

How can I get templating to work by the key/value to share the same name?